# Problem running docker image from my own public repo from docker hub

Tags: docker

I have a repo in docker hub named shaktidocker and it is public. I have a image in the repo.

When i am trying to run that image from my local docker development host using next command:

```
docker run -P -d shaktidocker/docker-spring-boot-demo
```

It gives me below error:

> e75c891fa5403b0bb6ed1aa3b5e6a6760d4707219ecaff22727632cca741fa25
>   /usr/bin/docker-current: Error response from daemon: linux spec user:
>   unable to find user shaktidocker: no matching entries in passwd file.

When I am trying t run a different image from different public repo, it works perfectly fine.

Please, advise

Answer (score 2):

The Dockerfile you used most likely contains the line:

```
USER shaktidocker
```

This is defining the Linux user inside the container to run commands, not your user ID on docker hub. Most likely you want to delete this line from your Dockerfile, rebuild, push, and pull your image, before trying to run it again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like for some reason when you want to start your container by default the name of repository is used as default username to run the container. This username does not exist in the underlying system hence container cannot start.

You can try to define a user with which you will start the image:

```
docker run -P -d --user nobody shaktidocker/docker-spring-boot-demo
```

This way you should be able to start your container.